# What is "performing penance"?

Tags: philosophy, upanishads

What is "performing penance" in Chapter 3 of the Taittiriya Upanishad, and what methods are involved? 
Performing penance is said to be the means of knowing Brahman, via the 5 koshas (sheaths).

Comment: Being an ascetic and doing Tapasya of Brahman like Lord Shiva and many yogis are depicted doing in their images and stories.

Comment: Thanks. I looked up tapasya and have a better idea now. Could you comment on how these ascetic practices lead to Brahman?

Comment: Tapasya is not some activity that can be forced upon body and mind, rather its the cessation of all body activities. Closing eyes in lotus posture and thinking of worldly things secretly is mere hypocrisy of Kaliyuga. Before understanding the relevance of Tapasya and Brahman, one should understand the Self first. For that study "Who am I?" https://realization.org/p/ramana/who-am-i.html by Ramana Maharshi.

Comment: The original Sanskrit word is "tapah", which means intense focus and "heating" which results in discovery of deep truth beyond the intellect. It is not merely physical torture as depicted in popular media and images and stories. This meaning is seen in the Tait. Up. where Bhrgu progressively discovers deeper and deeper truths about existence, until he discovers the ultimate truth.